# What is wrong with defining my fancybox like so?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In my fancybox, I'm trying to set the 'title' attribute to the alt value of an img wrapped by the fancybox link. In other words,

```
        $("a.fancypic").fancybox({
            'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
            'padding'           : 0,
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'href'              : this.href,
            'type'              :   'image',
            'title'             : this.find('img').attr( 'alt' )
                        });
```

When I remove the 'title' attribute, the fancybox works fine. However, with the 'title' attribute, the fancybox fails to show, and no error is shown in firebug. Any ideas on what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're using `this.href`, I'm going to guess that `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery selection. jQuery methods like `find` only work on jQuery selections.

So do this:

```
'title': $(this).find('img').attr( 'alt' )
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thanks for helping a jquery noob :)